# IONIC - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin

Tags: ionic-framework, woocommerce

I'm working on an ionic apps. My problem is : when i try to get data from server i got this :

```
Failed to load http://domainname.com/wc-api/v3/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_1152790ee6b10fd740b98fa9668fbea1fc9fddbc&oauth_nonce=7LPagE0ILZsYph7HU713hqHilIWBXvkc&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1506576888&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=iGGEJFI1d9p7FbxMjxyNmPFOxjos0dzVuVOAFPgR9LI%3D: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Please Help me, I have used woocommerce api but not able to get data.

Answer (score 1):

i got solution but i want to know is it ok?
i have used this extention of google play.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en